# React : Add backend filter to fetched data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I have the following component where I fetch data from a table, display them and have the ability to perform a search.

I want to add an additional filter to the fetched element. The filter is already coded and working in Laravel as following :

```
   public function search(Request $request){
        $search = $request ->get('q');
        $Patient = Patient::where('name','Like','%'.$search.'%');

        if ($request->has('gender')) {
            $Patient->where('gender', $request->gender);
        }
        return $Patient->get();
    }
```

As you can see in the controller you can perform a search and a filtering. So an example of directly accessing it will be :

```
http://localhost:8000/api/patients/search?q=John&gender=male
```

**For now I'm able to display data and search it in react, but I have no idea on how to add additional filters to the link to fetch from. How to do so ?**

Component :

```
  class Patient extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)          
            
            this.state = {
                patients : [],
            };
    
            this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
        }

  handleSearchChange(key){   
        console.log(key);       
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/patients/search?q='+key)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({
            patients: response})
            console.log(response);
        })     
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      } 
      
          
            componentDidMount() {
                axios.get('api/patients')
                .then(response => {
                  this.setState({
                    patients: response.data})
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));                
            }
    
            render() {
            return (
              <div>
                <Container>
                  <div>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Search..."
                        onChange={e => this.handleSearchChange(e.target.value)}
                      /> 

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button

      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Male</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Female</a>
      </div>
    </div>
                  </div>
        
                  <Table>
                    <Thead>
                      <Tr>
                        <Th>ID</Th>
                        <Th>FIRST NAME</Th>
                        <Th>LAST NAME</Th>
                      </Tr>
                    </Thead>
        
                    <Tbody>
        
                      {this.state.patients.reverse().map((patient) => (
                        <Tr>
                          <Td>
                            {patient.id}
                          </Td>
                          <Td>
                            {patient.firstname}
                          </Td>
                          <Td>
                            {patient.lastname}
                          </Td>
                        </Tr>
                      ))}
        
                    </Tbody>
        
                  </Table>
                </Container>
              </div>
            );
          }
        }
        
        export default Patient;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close to it.

Your current implementation generates the search `url` as soon as the `<input>` field changes. If you want some other filters, you will need to store those filters values in a state before actually generating the url and fetching the data.

Here is how the gist would look like.

```js
class Patient extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)          
        this.state = {
           patients : [],
           filters: {q: '', gender: ''} // we add the filter property to the state
        };
        this.updateFilter = this.updateFilter.bind(this);
    }

    // this will fetch the new patients as soon as one of the filter has been updated
    fetchPatients() {
      const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      const {q, gender} = this.state.filters
      if (q) {
        searchParams.set('q', q);
      }
      if (gender) {
        searchParams.set('gender', gender);
      }
      const url = `http://localhost:8000/api/patients/search?${searchParams.toString()}`;
      fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => this.setState({patients: response}))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    // this will update a single filter
    updateFilter(filter, value) {
      const currentFilters = this.state.filters;
      this.setState({filters: {...currentFilters, [filter]: value}});
      this.fetchPatients()
    } 

    render() {
      return (
        /*...*/
        <input type="text" onChange={ev => this.updateFilter('q', ev.target.value)} />
        /*...*/
        <input type="text" onChange={ev => this.updateFilter('gender', ev.target.value)} />
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I understood the logic behind your code, the inputs doesn't seem to work. I tried to wrap them in a `<form>` but failed to do so, any ideas ?

Comment: I also added key to `fetchPatients(key)` because key was not recognised.

Comment: Actually `console.log(response);` returns an empty array.

Comment: Woups, indeed, I forgot to replace the `fetch` by `fetch(url)`. 
I cannot really test the code I write here, so you will need to adapt a few things here and there. This gives you the basic idea behind it :)
I hope this helps

Comment: I see. Well still empty array. I tried to set `fetchPatients` in the onChange and it worked with the previous `url`, the new one you provided doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the `gender` is always there (I didn't condition it for the sake of simplicity). I think you will need to *not* add it in the url, in case it's empty.

Comment: So should I put a condition where a custom `url` is generated when gender is empty ? Because I removed gender on my last test and it's still not working. What worked for me was `fetchPatients` with old url. `updateFilter` doesn't work at all.

Comment: It is quite hard to understand what is happening here since I cannot run the code. What do you mean the updateFilter doesn't work? What is the url that is called when you send the request? What does this url returns when you call it in a browser?

Comment: When I try `onChange={ev => this.updateFilter('q', ev.target.value)} `, it gives me an empty array. When I try `onChange={ev => this.fetchPatients( ev.target.value)} ` it gives me empty array,  and when I try the same `onChange={ev => this.fetchPatients( ev.target.value)} ` but this time with `fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/patients/search?q='+key)` instead of `fetch(url)` it shows me an actual array of data. Sorry for any misunderstanding. If you don't have any idea then it's no problem I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you see the request that is sent to the server in your browser's devtools ?

Comment: Haha it's working ! But it's so weird I have to time in gender "malee" instead of "male", it seems like this first letter is empty.

Comment: Yeah ok, so I am pretty sure because there is an empty `gender` params the server returns an empty response. You need to condition the `gender` parameter in the url. If it's empty you should (either on the server side or the client side) ignore it

Comment: Ah well it didn't workout, but now I have an idea about the condition, I will see what I can do. Anyway thank you veru much, really appreciated your help !

Answer (score 0):

[check this example from pingcrm](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/resources/js/Pages/Contacts/Index.vue) (build with laravel, inertiajs and vue), specifically when use lodash/pickBy conversion to replace a request URL

```js
form: {
  handler: throttle(function() {
    let query = pickBy(this.form)
    this.$inertia.replace(this.route('contacts', Object.keys(query).length ? query : { remember: 'forget' }))
  }, 150),
  deep: true,
},
```

Hope help.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, I'm still a complete newbie in React and while you example is interesting I can't understand yet a lot of things there. Anyway appreciated.

Comment: Anyway, I recommend use [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes](Eloquent Query Scopes) to filtering data, see a example of the Model here https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/app/Models/Contact.php and the controller example here https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ContactsController.php Maybe that can be more Laravel way. I hope have more time to post a lodash/pickby example for you. Regards

Comment: I see. Now I understand a little bit because I have some knowledge in Laravel. Yes I was thinking about filtering data in backend rather than front so your option is correct. Thanks.